# Magento 2 prevent clearing cache on product save in Admin

Tags: cache, full-page-cache

When I edit product or products in admin, after save, Magento clear cache. Now, When I decide to change 1 product this is ok, but when I want to made changes on 100 product, this is quite annoying....

For example.. I rewrite descriptions on each product... I need for this 1, 2 or 3 minutes. After I save product, cache is cleared and as shop is live, whole shop is working slow until recached is made by page visit (FPC).. but if I am changing texts for more product whole day, then whole day I am out of cached pages...

So, question is is there any possibilities to prevent clearing cache and for example after the end of the day I manually refresh FPC cache?

Comment: use magento import functionality in that case, if you want to update more products data import would be nicer solution

Comment: yes, I know for this option, but here are changing content for SEO and design needs.. so its hard to do it via IMPORT function from Magento, which is so - so.